# Node - express-http-proxy - set Header before proxying

Tags: node.js, http, express, proxy

Before I proxy to a address I want to set the header of the proxy (Smth like an interceptor). I use the express-http-library and express with Node.JS. So far my code looks as follow. Btw. the docs of this library did not make me any wiser.

```
app.use('/v1/*', proxy('velodrome.usefixie.com', {
userResHeaderDecorator(headers, userReq, userRes, proxyReq, proxyRes) {
    // recieves an Object of headers, returns an Object of headers.
    headers = {
        Host: 'api.clashofclans.com',
        'Proxy-Authorization': `Basic ${new Buffer('token').toString('base64')}`
    };
    console.log(headers);

    return headers;
}
```

}));

And even though the console prints me out the headers obj. as expected the proxy authorization did not work:

```
{ Host: 'api.clashofclans.com',
  'Proxy-Authorization': 'Basic token' }
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: the answer I provided is more complete than the accepted answer and it continues to get upvotes even now, 3 years later... could you please mark my answer as the accepted one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is add some middleware to change some headers, you should be able to just do something like this:

```
app.use('/v1/*', (req, res, next) => {
    req.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = `Basic ${new Buffer('token').toString('base64')}`;
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 9):

`express-http-proxy` allows you to pass in an options object (same object as used in the `request` library) via `proxyReqOptDecorator`:

```
app.use("/proxy", proxy("https://target.io/api", {
  proxyReqOptDecorator: function (proxyReqOpts, srcReq) {
    proxyReqOpts.headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer token"};
    return proxyReqOpts;
  }
}));
```

or

```
app.use("/proxy", proxy("https://target.io/api", {
  proxyReqOptDecorator: function (proxyReqOpts, srcReq) {
    proxyReqOpts.auth = `${username}:${password}`;
    return proxyReqOpts;
  }
}));
```

The documentation for `proxyReqOptDecorator` can be found [here](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy#proxyreqoptdecorator--supports-promise-form)